# Discount by time and not by date

Tags: commerce

How can I achieve the discount by time on not by date functionality.
I have to provide discount on 8 March from 8AM to 8PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) doesn't support specific times in it's discount rules.

You could use PHP evaluation to make this work, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show date-time you can try this:
https://www.drupal.org/project/stanford_date_timepicker

alter file commerce_discount.admin.inc

```
$element['date']['#title'] = t('Start date');
// New class to show date time like 03/22/2017 12:32
$element['date']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'stanford-timepicker';
$element['date']['#description'] = t('Starts at 12:00:00 AM');
```

Note: need to change the tables accordingly.